# Is there a name for a style with black outlines and flat colors?

Tags: drawing, style-identification, sprite

It's always tricky to look for something when what you need is the name. I'm working on a videogame and I'd like to give general instructions for sprites.

This is an example of the style I'm talking about:

[image]

The defining traits are:

- Black outline, often fairly big
- Flat colors, generally one color by material + one simple layer of shading
- Lighting only when necessary (shiny surfaces), if so it's one shade and/or white
- No gradients

You can almost see the graphic tablet pen line sometimes.

Maybe there's a single word or term I'm missing, but I'm not a native English speaker and neither is any of the team members.

Comment: There's not a specific name for everything. There likely isn't a specific name for this "style"

Comment: @ZachSaucier I know it's not really a style, but using very little colors + a simple shade could have a name. Many animated shows use something similar.

Answer (score 4):

If you are starting with a 3d model, then the term would be cel shading.  The style emulates cartoons or comic book illustrations.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading

Comment: I'm not! It's all 2D. I think I would have referenced the Sly series or Borderlands in that case. Thanks though.

Comment: Its still called cell shading in 2D because thats the name of the method used by hand animators... which obviously is 2D.